# Select box appearance issue with Safari

Tags: css, safari, webkit

I am writing a login page for my intranet. I've got a problem with the css: the select box (to select the username) does not render properly on Safari 8.0 (it's glossy, it shouldn't be. See screenshots for details) and the password form has a size problem on Mobile Safari on iOS 8.

**Screenshots**: http://imgur.com/a/em540

**CSS:**

```
    #login #container form {
    width: 10rem;
    margin: 2rem auto auto auto;
    color: #2C2C2C;
    }

    #login #container form select {
    width: inherit;
    border: 0;
    background-color: #171717;
    color: inherit;
    }

    #login #container form input {
    width: inherit;
    margin: 0.75rem auto auto auto;
    border: 0;
    background-color: #171717;
    text-align: center;
    color: inherit;
    }
```